# Setting MySQL connection/server to utf8mb4 instead of uft8 is breaking stored procedures in SQLYog

Tags: mysql, utf-8, sqlyog, utf8mb4

Whether I try to open the stored procedures or create a new one SQLYog is giving the following error:
`COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'`

They can execute correctly from the server, but on SQLYog they keep giving this error code.

I temporarily solved the issue with `SET collation_connection = @@collation_database;` but I was wondering if there's a more permanent solution?

Comment: What version of SQLyog and MySQL are you using?.

Comment: MySQL version 5.5 and SQLYog version 11.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SQLyog:

```sql
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8_bin';

Error Code: 1253
COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
```

try:

```sql
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_bin';
```

Using SQLyog Community v12.2.2 (64 bit) and MySQL 5.5.49 can modify (open) and create new stored procedures without problem.

```sql
VERSION()
-----------
5.5.49

SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE  'utf8mb4_bin';

SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_bin',
            collation_server = 'utf8mb4_bin',
            collation_database = 'utf8mb4_bin';

SHOW VARIABLES WHERE
    `Variable_Name` != 'character_sets_dir' AND
    (`Variable_Name` LIKE '%CHAR%' OR
    `Variable_Name` LIKE '%COLL%');

Variable_name             Value        
------------------------  -------------
character_set_client      utf8mb4      
character_set_connection  utf8mb4      
character_set_database    utf8mb4      
character_set_filesystem  binary       
character_set_results     utf8mb4      
character_set_server      utf8mb4      
character_set_system      utf8         
collation_connection      utf8mb4_bin  
collation_database        utf8mb4_bin  
collation_server          utf8mb4_bin
```